# Connection problem with RS485 system on PC with RS232 port

Tags: communication, rs232, rs485

I am developing a system in which I have to integrate hardware. I am from computer background, so I don't have much knowledge about hardware systems.

The issue is I have to integrate with London based taximeter [with MR400S model](http://www.taxiworld.co.uk/london/taximeter-rentals). This taximeter gives output according to RS485 system. My application is on PC and I want to receive signal from this taximeter. My PC can read data from RS232 cable. I have RS232 cable so I have connected the RX and TX of taximeter to TX and Rx of cable. But my PC is not detecting this hardware, so can anyone help me solve this issue?

Comment: RS485 is not RS232, you need a USB-RS485 adapter, they are only about £5 from eBay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This taximeter gives output according to RS485 system. My application
>   is on PC and I want to receive signal from this taximeter. My PC can
>   read data from RS232 cable. I have RS232 cable so I have connected the
>   RX and TX of taximeter to TX and Rx of cable.

RS485 is not compatible with RS232 hardware wise at all. RS485 uses a balanced, differential 2-wire or 4-wire transmission/reception circuit. RS232 uses single ended transmit and receive wires (and ground) and has no facility to accept 485 without a 485 converter.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Lets assume I have RS485 cable and RS-485 to USb converter, but how would I come to know that my hardware has been connected to PC? I don't have any driver. Do  I check directly in the device manager?

Comment: Hey you are from london, you must have seen MR400 taximeter in the london taxi.

Comment: I'm not from London and even if I were I'm not a taxi driver but supposing I were both a Londoner and a taxi driver, what's the chances of me wanting to connect my taximeter to a PC? Yes you will need a driver but this has now stepped away from your original question and is probably better suited to a different stack exchange site.

Comment: Can I see hardware detected in the ports section in Control Panel-> System->Device Manger -> expand Ports? Beacuse I dont have any driver to connect to PC.

Comment: I don't know, can you? I'm mainly a hardware guy and your question is about RS232 and RS485. I've told you the reason why - they are not compatible so, any talk about drivers in PCs is irrelevant.

Comment: RS485 to USB look like a Serial Port....the last one I saw was supported by windows out of the box. For extra functionality the makers drivers are recommended tho.

Comment: @ishanjain - no you will not see in your device manager if there is any device plugged into the far end of your RS232 or RS485 cable. These old interfaces do not work like USB where there is a lot of info & negotiation between the PC and device when it gets plugged in. Typically the only way to find out if there's anything there is to try to initiate some communication with it and see what you get back ...